# Initially set the field value and then it should be available for change

Tags: workflow

I have a 'File Date' field. 
This should be initially set when the Status field gets set to "Testing" the first time and is available to be manually changed after that.

I am trying to do this using workflow. But not able to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow rule formula:

```
IF(ISBLANK(File_Date__c ) && TEXT(Status__c) = 'Testing')
```

Field update:

```
File_Date__c = TODAY (or whatever date it needs to be)
```

Then once this is ran the first time, the File_Date__c is filled and it won't be triggered again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value to field: [image]

And in input just right: `TODAY()`. You don't need to use workflow for this. On each new record insert if you left the field `File_Date__c` blank it will insert current date.